# preg_split(): Subject is too long

Tags: php, function, file, preg-match

I'm trying to parse a file content into an array, actually the preg_match works well but with a large file it throws me the follow error:

```
Warning: preg_split(): Subject is too long in /var/www/html/script.php on line 81
```

I'm trying with this code:

```
$fileLines = file($file);
    foreach ($fileLines as $line) {
        $rows = preg_split('/\n/', $line);
        $rowCount = 0;
        // THEN I PROCESS THE ROWS
    }
}
```

The actual file size is almost 2.5Gb, and I think is not a memory problem because I already increase the memory in the VPS and changed the configuration files.

Any idea?

Comment: tried explode? you dont need a regular expression here

Comment: Already, yes. But only this function splits the file correctly. 
I put like $rows = explode("\n", $line); and it returns me an array with 1 length with the complete string.

Comment: sure its not \n\r or even \r

Comment: Have you ever tried with fopen?

Answer (score 0):

You should read line by line:

```
$handle = fopen("inputfile.txt", "r");
if ($handle) {
    while (($line = fgets($handle)) !== false) {
        // process the line read.
    }
    fclose($handle);
} else {
    // error opening the file.
}
```

No matter how big is your file, you are going to be able to process it.